# Find time difference between two most recent orders

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to estimate the time of a new order from repeat customers by finding the time difference between the most recent order and the second most recent order, and then adding that difference to the most recent order.

I have been trying limit and offset, but this returns a blanket date for every row. I am thinking I need to do a lateral join, but not sure how to implement it correctly. When I try to do it, I receive no output.

```
select public.orders.customer_id,
       max(public.orders.created_at) as last_order_date,
       (select created_at from public.orders group by created_at order by created_at desc limit 1 offset 1) as second_last
from public.orders
inner join
(select
customer_id, count(*)
from public.orders
where status  = 'fulfilled'
group by public.orders.customer_id
having count(customer_id) >1) repeat_customers
on public.orders.customer_id = repeat_customers.customer_id
group by public.orders.customer_id;
```

I wanted the second_last field to be populated by the second most recent date for each customer_id, but the output is the second most recent date for the entire table, resulting in the same date for every entry.

Answer (score 0):

For your `second_last` column you're not limiting it per customer, it will indeed find the max of everything just like the results you've seen. See the `WHERE` clause in the example below which should solve this:

```sql
(SELECT
    created_at
FROM
    public.orders po
WHERE
    po.customer_id = customer_id
ORDER BY
    created_at
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS second_last
```

I've also aliased the table because I wasn't sure if it would complain about ambiguity since the same table is mentioned in the main select.